# UIImage imageWithData

Tags: iphone, uiimage, memory-management

I have a `UITable` and when I click on a row I load a set of images.
I create the images with

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

The problem is that ever time I click on the same row, the images are re-allocated into memory, like if no cache it is used and no memory is freed, so the allocated memory keep increasing. (I see this using the Inspector on both the device and the emulator)

I am releasing everything and also, with clang, everything looks fine.
The point is that after a while my app crashes.

Any suggestion or idea?

EDIT:

Here is the portion of code I think is generating the issue:

```
UIView *main = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rectScrollView] autorelease];

    for (int i=0; i<[contentArray count]; i++) {
        float targetWidth = rectScrollView.size.width;
        float targetHeight = rectScrollView.size.height;

        Link *tmp_link = [contentArray objectAtIndex:i];
        AsyncImageView* asyncImage = nil;
        if(tmp_link!=nil){
            CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(targetWidth*i, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight); 
            //asyncImage = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame ] autorelease];
            asyncImage = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame ];
            asyncImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[IMG_SERVER_URL stringByAppendingString: tmp_link.url] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:url];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:(UIImageView *)asyncImage];
            [asyncImage release];
        }

        if ([tmp_link.caption length] > 0 && asyncImage!=nil) {
            float marginTop = 25;

            UILabel *caption = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            caption.text = tmp_link.caption;
            caption.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            caption.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            caption.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            caption.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.4];

            CGRect captionFrame = CGRectMake((i * targetWidth), marginTop+10, targetWidth, 20.0f);
            caption.frame = captionFrame;   
            [self.scrollView addSubview:caption];
            [caption release];
        }
        //[asyncImage release];
    }
    [main addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView release];
    if (pageControlEnabledTop) {
        rectPageControl = CGRectMake(0, 5, scrollWidth, 15);
    }
    else if (pageControlEnabledBottom) {
        //rectPageControl = CGRectMake(0, (scrollHeight - 25), scrollWidth, 15);
        rectPageControl = CGRectMake(0, (scrollHeight), scrollWidth, 15);
    }
    if (pageControlEnabledTop || pageControlEnabledBottom) {
        //pageControl = [[[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:rectPageControl] autorelease];
        pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:rectPageControl];
        pageControl.numberOfPages = [contentArray count];
        pageControl.currentPage = page;
        [main addSubview:pageControl];
        [pageControl release];
    }
    if (pageControlEnabledTop || pageControlEnabledBottom || rememberPosition) self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    //if (margin) [margin release];
    return (UIScrollView *)main;
```

And it is used like this:

```
reviewImagesImage = [[IGUIScrollViewImage alloc] init];
        if([currentReview.linkScreenshots count]>0){

            //reviewImages
            reviewImages = [[UIView alloc] init];

            //placing the images
            CGRect frameImages = reviewImages.frame;
            frameImages.origin.x = 10;
            frameImages.origin.y = (infoView.frame.origin.y + infoView.frame.size.height + 10.0f);
            frameImages.size.width = 300;
            frameImages.size.height = 350.0f;
            reviewImages.frame = frameImages;
            reviewImages.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];
            [reviewImagesImage setContentArray:currentReview.linkScreenshots];
            [reviewImagesImage setWidth:reviewImages.frame.size.width andHeight: reviewImages.frame.size.height];
            [reviewImagesImage enablePageControlOnBottom];
            [reviewImagesImage setBackGroudColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
            UIScrollView *tmp_sv = [reviewImagesImage getWithPosition:0];
            [reviewImages addSubview:tmp_sv];
            [self.view addSubview:reviewImages];
                    [reviewImages release];
        }
```

I have noticed that if I try to release `reviewImagesImage` my app crashes :/

Comment: Can you post more code? Perhaps you haven't released your data somewhere?

Comment: When do you release your `reviewImage`?

Comment: Good point, I am releasing it after [self.view addSubview:reviewImages]; [reviewImages release];

Comment: but it is not solving the problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Of course no cache is used because new UIImage will be created from the data every time. If memory usage significantly increased like you have said, it is most likely that it is our fault that unintentionally keep the reference retained somewhere.

Comment: well, thanks for the answer... but I was hoping in some suggestions on how to solve the issue...

Comment: Post some more code? Run it in Leaks? It sounds like the UIImageView you're presumably displaying it in isn't being released, which might happen if it's an IBOutlet loaded in a nib that isn't released in `-dealloc`.

Comment: When this happened, I just look at my code to find where I might went wrong. Then if that doesn't work, I would try to remove suspicious sections until my application run fine so I know where the culprit is. If it is possible for you to post more of your code, people here might be able to help.

Comment: I have added a snippet of code, Sorry for have answered in a bitchy way, I think I was a bit frustrated

Comment: That's ok. Now I see your code, but you didn't give us the portion of code that you release your stuff, so it's still impossible to validate the memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've set your `image` with `imageWithData`, save the `image` to the `filepath` in the app bundle.